# How to back up iPhone with iOS 11.3 via iTunes on a Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

When I plug my iPhone 7 (iOS 11.3) into my Mac (macOS 10.13.4), I see the following categories in iTunes (12.7.4):

[image]

I don't see any way to do backups.  How do I do local backups with the latest iOS / MacOS?

Answer (score 3):

In the iTunes window, click on Summary. Under Backups, click on **Back Up Now** button.

[image]

Comment: there's no summary window that's what I'm showing in my screenshot

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the entire window? Is the device detected by iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

In the fall of 2017, Apple introduced iTunes 12.7, which removed the ability to backup locally as well access the App Store. A significant number of users disliked this change, as many of us prefer local backups, and find it much easier to navigate and review apps on macOS than on an iOS device.

A month or so later, Apple retreated and offered iTunes 12.6.3. 12.6.3 restores the ability to create local backups and allows access to the iOS App Store. It's described on [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208079). iTunes 12.6.3 can be installed even if one has already installed 12.7. The Apple page cited above contains a link to download iTunes 12.6.3.

@Nimesh's answer is better than mine...because I retreated immediately to iTunes 12.6.3, I never discovered that 12.7 does contain the ability to backup locally.